# I dont wanna texture the inner parts!

Tags: texturing, uv

I am learning texturing, and after creating my building using UV grid before exporting my map, I realized that the inner part of my building is unwrapped too. Isn't there a way to avoid this? I want to texture only the "outside". Also, the second picture shows a part of my mesh that is clearly not the same size of the building in the map, which I don't understand because I have the same triangle on the other side and it is correct. How can I fix this?

I am also looking for good UV mapping courses for games etc... I have watched several videos on youtube, but I always end up getting confused. I believe I will have to pay for a course and ask questions directly to understand the whole process of UV's, - not for texture painting but for placed 2D images.

[image]

[image: I dont know , it seem to have a diferent size]

[image: This one is correct]

Comment: Don't sweat it too much - every artist hates UV mapping. Learning it's ins and outs is just gonna take some time and focus, no way around it. Before going the paid course route, though, take a look at this guide. It's long, but everything's there - https://artisticrender.com/the-definitive-tutorial-to-uv-mapping-in-blender/

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you so much :)!